# JTextArea doesn't list out results

Tags: java, swing, rss, textarea

I am trying the RSS Feed code from this website (http://javamix.wordpress.com/category/programs/rss-feed/) It worked fine. I would like to display results in GUI instead. I've created a JTextArea to append the elements but the results is 'loaded' instead of being listed out. Thanks.

Original:

```
System.out.println("Title: " + getElementValue(element,"title"));
System.out.println("Link: " + getElementValue(element,"link"));
System.out.println("Publish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate"));
```

I've created a JTextArea to display the result:

```
for (int i-0; i<nodes.getLength();i++)
{
     Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);

     JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
     textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 864, 540);
     textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
     getContentPane().add(textArea);

     textArea.append("Title: " + getElementValue(element,"title") + "\n");
     textArea.append("Link: " + getElementValue(element,"link") + "\n");
     textArea.append("Publish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate") + "\n"); 
}
```

I'm a new user and not allowed to upload pictures, but there's the link :) I need a full list of results, displayed in the GUI.

My result (Title, Link, Publish Date remains static while the result was loaded) >>> Refer Screenshot [My Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6ix8.png)

Console (A full list of result)  >>> Refer Screenshot [Console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2f3Tj.png)

Comment: Your textarea code looks fine. Are you sure that this is the only change you made?

Comment: I do not really see the difference between your result and what you need. Do you have a concrete example, or perhaps a screenshot

Comment: Wouldn't you, by mistake recreate the textArea everytime? Just a short in the dark.

Comment: @erikxiv, Yes that's the only change. Please check the screenshot.

Comment: @Robin, i've just included the screenshot in the link. please check!

Comment: So...the issue is that you are only displaying one news article rather than all of them?

Comment: @GuillaumePolet, Hmm..I did append in the for loop. Is that the problem?

Comment: @broarrkid no, it shouldn't. It would, if the creation of the textarea was done in the loop.

Comment: @YoussefG. All the articles are returned, but it's loaded into the textarea instead of listed. Title, Link and Date remains static while the results load.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are making a new `TextArea` every time in the Loop.
Move the declaration and instatiation of the `TextArea` to before the loop.

Like this:

```
JTextArea textArea = new JTextArea();
textArea.setBounds(10, 11, 864, 540);
textArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);
getContentPane().add(textArea);
for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength();i++)
{
     Element element = (Element)nodes.item(i);

     textArea.append("Title: " + getElementValue(element,"title") + "\n");
     textArea.append("Link: " + getElementValue(element,"link") + "\n");
     textArea.append("Publish Date: " + getElementValue(element,"pubDate") + "\n"); 
}
```

Comment: Your welcome. Please upvote, and unless you think there is a need to wait for better answer also accept.

Comment: i'm still a new user, can't upvote until i have 15 reputation score :( thanks for your help tho!